# Cylinder radial extrusion connected to other faces

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

How do I make so that this shape on a cylinder can be reapplied to all other faces radially without them connecting? 
This should look like a bevel gear.
I suppose I could use Array modifier, but I'm afraid the wider part won't be connected to the initial cylinder.

[image: Blender viewport of a single part]
[image: Reference gears, the ones at the top and bottom]

Comment: does it mean that it should look like the one on the left (the one on the right would be one face out of 2): https://zupimages.net/up/23/24/rv78.jpg and what do you mean by not connected? Maybe show a reference image of the object?

Comment: https://mechanical-engineering.s3.amazonaws.com/gallery/album_133/gallery_53_133_9465.jpg
Basically something like this.
I feel like most modifiers will just copy the shape and won't connect the copied ones to the wider cylinder part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you show, you can easily do it with a portion of a 32 vertices cylinder, remove 30/32 and give it an *Array* modifier with its *Object Offset* option, choose an empty as object and put it at the same location as the cylinder origin:

[image]

Then rotate 22.5° on Z the empty:

[image]